# Fallout Shelter typical amount of time before finding Red Rocket location

Tags: fallout-shelter

I've noticed that when I sent out people into the wasteland they almost always, if not always, stumble upon the Red Rocket event first.

Is there a typical or average amount of time that it takes to reach this.

Knowing this would be helpful in that I might check in with them at that time so as to not miss the event or have it trigger so that I can help reach additional events (not sure how that works).

Comment: Things don't actually happen while you're not playing. You can't miss it like that, and it won't block anything else.

Comment: Ya that does make sense too because it doesn't seem to matter if a small or great amount of time passes - it's pretty much always the first event that's triggered while wandering.

Answer (score -1):

This is a random event, there is no set timer for it according to http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Red_Rocket_truck_stop_(Fallout_Shelter)

Comment: That doesn't stop there being an expected amount of time before finding it.